# Update key vault's assiciated Azure AD tenant after subscriptin move without having to do a synchronized deployment of all dependent apps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I am moving subscriptions from one tenant of Azure AD to another. I have reviewed and followed the process outlined in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory). Everything is fine. The next step is about changing the key vault tenant ID for the moved subscription as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-subscription-move-fix). This is where I can't figure out a way to do it in such a way that doesn't involve changing and deploying several application dependent on the Key Vault together with the move. Ideally I would like to associate second tenant (the new one) with the key vault, register the apps in the new tenant and let those application update the configs as per their own release cycle and once all of the applications have updated to use new ClientID/Secret generated in the new Azure AD tenant, I would remove the old tenant association. However a key vault can only be associated with one tenant at any given time. What strategy can be used to allow this transition in smooth fashion without forcing a synchronized deployment of all of the dependent application in one go? It seems the only solution is to create a new key vault associated with the new AD tenant, register apps and issue new ClientID/Secret and let those go live as per their own deployment schedule. Eventually old key vault can be deleted. This seems to be a rather cumbersome approach. Is there any other way?

To make matter even more complicated, storage accounts keys are configured to be [managed by key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys) and all of the applications use [key vault to get access to storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/storage-keys-sas-tokens-code) rather than directly using storage account keys. Here also the storage account can only be linked and managed by a single key vault.

> Only a single Key Vault object should manage storage account keys.
>   Don't allow key management from multiple objects.

This would mean even the approach of creating new key vaults and migrating all apps to use these won't work unless the update to the storage-key vault link is synchronized with and deployment of all of the applications that use such storage. Some of these apps are managed by different teams in different timezones so a synchronized deployment is rather difficult plus if any of the app deployment were to rollback, it would either lose access to storage accounts or all of the apps have to rollback.

While this may not be a frequent situation where the subscriptions are moved to a different Azure AD tenant, I am sure it has been done and that is why I would like to get some guidance to how to do this without having to do a synchronized deployments of all of the key vault dependent apps.

**Update 1**

It so turns out that after moving the subscriptions, the key vault access is in really messed up state. The old tenant's users can't see even the key vault as there is no subscription and new tenant's users can't do anything (can't see keys, secrets, certs or update access policy) as long as key vault's tenant is still old. If the key vault updated to the new tenant, the users still can't see existing keys, secrets and certs. They do get access to update the access policy but the existing keys, secrets and certs are not even viewable from the portal. The Powershell can list/view these but can't update any values! so there is a discrepancy there too. Can someone from Key Vault team confirm these or there should be a big red warning in the Tenant move that it would invalidate access to any existing keys, secrets and certs.

Answer (score 0):

Having a KeyVault move tenants keeps the old tenant value so that existing access policies do not fail.  However, when the tenant value is updated to the new tenant, old access policies are invalidated because the identities do not exist in the new tenant and they must be recreated using new identities.  This is by-design.  Although not official documentation, I blogged about this a while back:

https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/05/16/azure-key-vault-known-portal-issues-the-directory-currently-selected-differs-from-this-key-vault-s-directory

Comment: Thanks Matt. The symptom and the reason is clear but knowing that this is by-design how would one move the tenant without disruptions in any applications that use the key vault. The details are in the question but I can clarify more if needed.

Comment: You can't avoid disruption.  You will have to recreate every access policy with a new SP in the new tenant for applications using that Key Vault.